# copy-item recurse, but exclude all subfolders

Tags: powershell

I'm using a CSV file to direct the copying of many directories and files. I created my example from this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965617/powershell-copy-directories-using-a-csv-listing-source-destination-path). Additionally, I want to selectively enable recursion. Some lines I only want to copy files inside source directory (**0**), and ignore subfolders within. Others, I want to copy everything (**1**). Essentially the question is how do I execute Copy-Item for **only** files inside a given directory. A lot of the answers on here pertain to excluding specific folders.

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vgSb.jpg)

**Attempt 1**

```
Import-CSV C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\test1.csv | foreach{
    If ($_.Recurse -eq 1){
        Copy-item  -Path $_.Source -Destination $_.Destination -Recurse
    } Else {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Source -Recurse -File | 
            Where-Object{ $_.PSIsContainer -eq $False } | 
            ForEach-Object {
                $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $_.Destination -Force
            }
    }
}
```

Nothing seems to happen on non-recurse items

**Attempt 2**

```
Import-CSV C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\test1.csv | foreach{
    If ($_.Recurse -eq 1){
        Copy-item -Path $_.Source -Destination $_.Destination -Recurse -Force
    } Else {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Source -Recurse -Depth 0 | Copy-Item -Destination $_.Destination
    }
}
```

Doesn't work, and recursed folders are copied as files

Comment: PLEASE do not post images of sample data. do you REALLY want to force those who want to help you to type in the text that you already have as text? [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey more than anything, the image was for clarification on what I was doing. They're paths to local files on my computer, I never expected anyone to have to type anything from it. Sorry.

Comment: not a problem - at 1st sight, it is not all that obvious that posting a picture of text to a text-oriented site is ... counter productive. [*grin*] still, please post the text, not an image of the text.